# Node.js pass handle of response object handle to child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, child-process

I have an `http` server and a forked child process. I want the parent to receive requests and pass to forked process using `worker.send`. and the worker should be able to process and send the response back to the requester using the same response object.

I tried sending the response object in the second parameter of `worker.send`, but it gives the error `This handle type can't be sent`

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var worker = child_process.fork(filename);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    worker.send({ 'event': 'start' }, res); // send response object
}).listen(4000);
```

I checked in the child_process.js file and it says if it doesn't belongs to some of the types, it will throw the error.

I want to know if there are any other options by which I can send the response object to the forked child.

**EDIT:**

Okay, here's what I found, I just changed the following

```
// Instead of
// worker.send({ 'event': 'start' }, res);
worker.send({ 'event': 'start' }, res.socket);
```

And the forked process is able to call `write` on the handler it gets.

Is it correct? Can I use it this way? or will there be any implications under some blah blah conditions?

Comment: Hi @Салман. Did you get any solution for this problem? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Nope, but I think I managed to solve it some other way not with this approach. If you have specific use case that you can share, you could find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The worker.send only takes requests coming from a net.createServer function. Try better with 'net' package instead of http. This resolved my issue